# printer/scanner driver for HP PSC 1210 on Windows XP?

Tags: drivers, printer, scanner

I'm selling our HP PSC 1210 printer/scanner to a colleague at work. She tried using it on a work computer running Windows XP, and after downloading a printer driver, can't seem to get the scanner to work, although the printer works fine.

(She called HP and they wouldn't talk to her since it's such an old printer. >:( )

Both scanner and printer have worked fine with our Mac OSX computers at home.

Any tips on how can we get this to work?

---

more info: We found the [software and driver page here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=228&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=90764#N191):

> HP Officejet and PSC Full Feature Software and Driver
>
> ►2004-04-30 , Version:2.1.0, 166.14M
>
> This download includes the HP Photosmart Software Suite (enhanced imaging features and product functionality) and Driver. If you only want the print driver (without the Photosmart Software Suite), it is available as a separate download named "HP Officejet and PSC Basic Software and Driver".

We balked at the 166MB download so searched for the "HP Officejet and PSC Basic Software and Driver" on google, and it returned several matches -- how do we know which is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a legacy product, that is likely the only download HP offers specifically for this model. The Photosmart series requires a software suite to run all the features of the printer/scanner/fax. I'd reccomend downloading it and putting it on a CD.

The link for the basic driver is below, but it will only "provide basic functionality", not scanning or fax.

[HP Officejet and PSC Basic Software and Driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=mp-23418-2)